# Updating data of old entities after adding a new column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm in a situation where I added a new field and everything works fine, but I would need to calculate the field for all older entities that didn't have the field before.

```
@Column(name = "actual_start_time")
private LocalDateTime actualStartTime;

@Column(name = "actual_end_time")
private LocalDateTime actualEndTime;

@Column(name = "elapsed_time")
private Long elapsedTime;
```

So I added a column to calculate the time between actualStartTime and actualEndTime in minutes. I need this to sort jobs with pageable.

Calculations and everything works fine with new jobs, but how can I take care of the old entries without having to change them all manually in the database?

Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE shift_job SET elapsed_time = ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM actual_end_time - actual_start_time)/60)
```

Ended up running this on SQL to solve my problem. Finds the difference in minutes and saves it to the elapsed_field column.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you needed to add a column for that in the first place, its a redundant information. You can do the sorting based on difference between columns this way:

```
  SELECT id, TIMEDIFF(actual_end_time, actual_start_time) AS elapsed_time
    FROM table_name
ORDER BY elapsed_time, id DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

This will order by the elapsed time then the id, take the second 10 records.

Using `@Query` as talked about in the comment on the answer

```
@Query("SELECT id, TIMEDIFF(actual_end_time, actual_start_time) AS elapsed_time
    FROM table_name
where table_name.prop = ?1
ORDER BY elapsed_time, id DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10")
  List<User> getPaginated(String search, int offset, int limit);
```

You can add more search options of course, look more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Comment: Im using Pageable to get paginated, filtered and sorted results. This sadly wouldn't be enough for me.

Comment: Updated my response :).

Comment: I have about 3000 records in the database, 15 filters and a search functionality. Pageable generates the SQL for me automatically. Maybe I could use a @Formula field with TIMEDIFF?

Comment: I dont think that will do for you, better use the @Query for getting the data. I will update my answer quick.

Comment: @HeikoPiirme you can use the answer provided by @Ali Ben Zarrouk, it is correct. However, u can also pass Pageable as parameter to such method if you want, there is no limitation on that. Try,
`@Query("SELECT id, TIMEDIFF(actual_end_time, actual_start_time) AS elapsed_time
    FROM table_name
where table_name.prop = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
public List<User> getPaginated(String search, Pageable pageable);`